# Homework/class help: Backward propagation of max pooling if each element in an array determines more than one value?

Tags: backpropagation

(This isn't actually my homework, and in fact wasn't addressed in my homework, but I was confused about this because my homework hadn't addressed this)

For example if I have an array:

[image]

And I do max pooling with:

filter size = 2x2

stride = 1

I get:
[image: -1 6 7 8 6 7 9 4 4 (Layer Ln+1)]

If I want to find the derivative from Ln+1 to Ln, I'm not sure what happens to the cell which would have contained the value 6 since it determines the output's center cell as well as the output's top middle cell.

[image]

I think I'm probably misunderstanding something about how to solve derivatives if it's connected to two equations.